# nginx access logs hang after it reach the limit

Tags: docker, nginx, logging, docker-compose, access-log

I use nginx as a container , and it looks like it reach the access logs limit and after 15 minutes of the run it hangs .
if I run nginx with acces_log off it works fine .
how can I solve the problem ?

I tried to use gzip=7 buffer=64k flush=3m; and it didn't help .

already tried gzip , filter logs and buffer .

I have a lot of unused disc space. so I think it is not related to disk space .

I use docker compose .(if it is related).

Comment: gzip did prevent the container from crashing but it is not a solution I can use .
because logs file is not bigger than 2mb .